# How to trap signals in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can we trap signals in shell script, where can we trap signals?

also can someone explain

```
 # trap commands signals
```

Comment: Wish you had searched on Google: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-signals-traps.htm

Comment: ps -aux command to get all the process...

Answer (score 2):

You can write a shell script :

```
trap ctl_c INT    # trap <name_of_function_to_called> <Signal to be handled>
function ctl_c(){

     // signal handling logic needed.
}
```

Now whenever you will send SIGINT (key-press CTRL + C), this function will get called, instead of default functionality.

Comment: +1 Note that the first argument to `trap` is a string to evaluate, not just the name of a single function, so you can pass arbitrary code. `trap 'handler1; echo "one down, one to go"; handler2' INT` would call a program or function called `handler1`, print a short status update, then call a second program/function.